# Can no longer open Flutter projects after updating my Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, flutter, android-studio-4.0

I recently updated my Android studio and when I tried opening previous projects this is the error it gave me.

> The IDE failed to install some plugins.
>
> Most probably, this happened because of a change in a serialization
> format. Please try again, and if the problem persists, please report
> it to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors
>
> The cause: /Users/mac/Library/Application
> Support/AndroidStudio4.0/firebase/lib/failureaccess-1.0.1.jar (No such
> file or directory)

The IDE also gives off these errors

> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio4.0/caches/contentHashes.dat_i
> (No such file or directory)   at
> com.intellij.util.ExceptionUtil.rethrow(ExceptionUtil.java:116)   at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.handleError(FSRecords.java:547)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$DbConnection.access$000(FSRecords.java:156)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.writeAndHandleErrors(FSRecords.java:999)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.access$300(FSRecords.java:49)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$ContentOutputStream.writeBytes(FSRecords.java:1563)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$ContentOutputStream.access$3200(FSRecords.java:1544)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.writeContent(FSRecords.java:1509)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.writeContent(PersistentFSImpl.java:243)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.PersistentFSImpl.contentsToByteArray(PersistentFSImpl.java:535)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.contentsToByteArray(VirtualFileImpl.java:139)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.impl.VirtualFileImpl.contentsToByteArray(VirtualFileImpl.java:130)
> at
> io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdkVersion.readVersionString(FlutterSdkVersion.java:85)
> at
> io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdkVersion.readFromFile(FlutterSdkVersion.java:73)
> at
> io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdkVersion.readFromSdk(FlutterSdkVersion.java:64)
> at io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdk.forPath(FlutterSdk.java:129)   at
> io.flutter.sdk.FlutterSdkUtil.addKnownSDKPathsToCombo(FlutterSdkUtil.java:105)
> at
> io.flutter.project.FlutterProjectStep.onWizardStarting(FlutterProjectStep.java:144)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.(ModelWizard.java:124)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard.(ModelWizard.java:47)
> at
> com.android.tools.idea.wizard.model.ModelWizard$Builder.build(ModelWizard.java:560)
> at
> io.flutter.actions.FlutterNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(FlutterNewProjectAction.java:53)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil$1.run(ActionUtil.java:298)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:315)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:474)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.invokeAction(ActionUtil.java:459)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink$1.linkSelected(ActionLink.java:45)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel.doClick(LinkLabel.java:142)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.components.labels.ActionLink.doClick(ActionLink.java:54)
> at
> com.intellij.ui.components.labels.LinkLabel$MyMouseHandler.mouseReleased(LinkLabel.java:330)
> at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6550)    at
> javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3325)    at
> java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6315)  at
> java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)  at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4899)     at
> java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)     at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)     at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
> at
> java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4535)
> at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
> at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)    at
> java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)   at
> java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4721)     at
> java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:766)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:98)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:715)    at
> java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
> at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
> at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:739)   at
> java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:737)    at
> java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
> java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
> at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:736)   at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:908)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchMouseEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:846)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:778)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$8(IdeEventQueue.java:424)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:698)
> at
> com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:423)
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
> at
> java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
> at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
> Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio4.0/caches/contentHashes.dat_i
> (No such file or directory)   at
> com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.doEnumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:304)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.enumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:317)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.findOrCreateContentRecord(FSRecords.java:1636)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.access$3600(FSRecords.java:49)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords$ContentOutputStream.lambda$writeBytes$0(FSRecords.java:1570)
> at
> com.intellij.openapi.vfs.newvfs.persistent.FSRecords.writeAndHandleErrors(FSRecords.java:996)
> ... 63 more Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
> java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio4.0/caches/contentHashes.dat_i
> (No such file or directory)   at
> com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.expand(ResizeableMappedFile.java:111)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.ensureSize(ResizeableMappedFile.java:77)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.putInt(ResizeableMappedFile.java:221)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.nextPage(IntToIntBtree.java:165)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.doAllocateRoot(IntToIntBtree.java:102)
> at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.doPut(IntToIntBtree.java:234)
> at com.intellij.util.io.IntToIntBtree.put(IntToIntBtree.java:229)   at
> com.intellij.util.io.PersistentBTreeEnumerator.enumerateImpl(PersistentBTreeEnumerator.java:476)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.PersistentEnumeratorBase.doEnumerate(PersistentEnumeratorBase.java:294)
> ... 68 more Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:
> /Users/mac/Library/Caches/AndroidStudio4.0/caches/contentHashes.dat_i
> (No such file or directory)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native
> Method)   at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
> at java.io.RandomAccessFile.(RandomAccessFile.java:243)   at
> com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resizeFile(PagedFileStorage.java:342)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.PagedFileStorage.resize(PagedFileStorage.java:325)
> at
> com.intellij.util.io.ResizeableMappedFile.expand(ResizeableMappedFile.java:108)
> ... 76 more

What does this mean and how do I resolve it?

Worst case, how do I downgrade back to what it was before?

Comment: Can you show which dependencies you are using in your pubspec.yaml file?

Comment: I can't open nor create any Flutter project. So it's not about issues with a dependency file